# Flash / AIR: saving, loading and splash screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, load, save

First of all, sorry for poor english :)

I will start by making a few clarifications: I decided to ask three questions together 'cause in my research I only found solutions incompatible with each other or mainly for platforms that I don't need.

Fact: I'm developing a game with Flash CS6. Not for browser, or mobile (not yet, at least) but a ***desktop*** game for Windows, Mac and Linux. I'm searching for:

1) I need to save the game progress. Nothing complex, mainly numeric vars. What is ***the best way*** to do it (file format, encryption etc)? How I do prevent rough solutions depending on events like cache cleaning etc? Can I choose where to save the files? Is there a difference between an automatic save mode and a manual mode?

2) Consequently, what is ***the best way*** to load this data?

3) What is the best way to create a splash screen at game start and at save game loading?

I'm very sorry for noob questions like these but I really can't understand by myself.

Thank u in advance.

ps: I think I'm going to use Zinc to build a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

For saving data, especially numeric values, you can always use SharedObject class. You can save any data, but works similar to cookies - different browser or computer - no access to the previously saved data, but for desktop game I don't think that is going to be a problem.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

If you decide to use external files, you can use xml files - they are the easiest, at least for me. Just google loading external files, and you'll find easy what you need. You can also try to use JSON format file.

As for the question 3 - I don't really understand what you're asking - best way to creat splash screen - in what way?

Comment: Thank u George. 

Uhm, but SharedOjbects are lost clearing the browser cache, right? I would avoid it.